# importxml to google spreadsheet with xpath returns FALSE

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a spreedsheet which is able to pull data from an remotely stored xml file. The xml has the following structure:

```
<response>
  <content>
        <measurements>
          <measurement>
            <from>2017-12-11T01:00:00+01:00</from>
            <to>2017-12-11T02:00:00+01:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">19</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
and so on ...
```

I try to extract the values with the label="fw" but it returns only FALSE or #N/A when using the following or a similiar syntax

```
={
  IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[name()='"&A2&"']/value/@label='fw'")
}
```

A1 is the URL (http://someurl.de/dir1/count-data_countdata_D8-80-39-D3-DD-C8_2017-12-12-01-00-00.xml - blanked out the real path)

A2 = values

XML is `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`

The URL is working because when I only try

```
 ={
  IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[name()='"&A2&"']")
}
```

it returns the values of both columns:

```
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
4   0
9   1
49  1
133 6
151 18
150 11
107 5
101 4
75  5
108 9
111 17
125 46
107 65
26  23
2   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: [Sample file](https://dropfile.to/kXe5PkH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? You can retrieve the value using `value[@label='fw']`.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[name()='"&A2&"']/value[@label='fw']")
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='value'][@label='fw']")
```

Comment: @dan_ke I'm sorry for the inconvenience. How about ``=IMPORTXML(A1,"//value[@label='fw']")``? And can you show us the URL at "A1"?

Comment: not working.
updated the url above but have to hide the real path but it points directly to the xml

Comment: @dan_ke Can you get the XML from ``http://someurl.de/dir1/count-data_countdata_D8-80-39-D3-DD-C8_2017-12-12-01-00-00.xml``? In my environment, I cannot retrieve XML data from the URL.

Comment: I had to blank out the real URL since this is company data but the url is working fine. I update the question with some more info.

Comment: @dan_ke I'm sorry for the inconvenience. If you can show us the XML sample, we can confirm the path of value. I have confirmed that in your current XML sample, ``=IMPORTXML(A1,"//value[@label='fw']")`` works.

Comment: please see above

Comment: @dan_ke Thank you for adding more information. Can you try ``=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[name()='"&A2&"']//*[name()='value'][@label='fw']")``?

Comment: @dan_ke I'm sorry for the inconvenience. When you try this ``=IMPORTXML(A1,"//@label='fw'")``, what value is returned?

Comment: it returns TRUE; further I've to add that it's not returning an error anymore when using on of you syntax without curly brackets

Comment: @dan_ke Thank you. So, can you try ``=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='value'][@label='fw']")``?

Comment: I'm relieved to hear that. I'm sorry for late answer.