# How to retrieve values using XmlService?

Tags: xml, dom, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It's kind of a follow-up question of my [recent task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782543/importxml-to-google-spreadsheet-with-xpath-returns-false)

I have to implement a pull of XML data in the Google spreadsheet by using the script editor. I'm trying to extract certain values from a remotely stored XML-file. The code can be static (index?) since the structure is fixed and only the values will change from time to time.

The XML looks as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<response xmlns="http://www.xovis.com/sensor-api/v2">
  <sensor-time timezone="Europe/Berlin">2017-12-18T17:00:02+01:00</sensor-time>
  <status>
    <code>OK</code>
  </status>
  <content>
    <elements>
      <element>
        <element-id>0</element-id>
        <element-name>count/element-name>
        <sensor-type>somesensor</sensor-type>
        <data-type>LINE</data-type>
        <from>2017-10-29T16:00:00+01:00</from>
        <to>2017-10-29T17:00:00+01:00</to>
        <resolution>ONE_HOUR</resolution>
        <measurements>
          <measurement>
            <from>2017-10-29T16:00:00+01:00</from>
            <to>2017-10-29T17:00:00+01:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">145</value>
              <value label="bw">1</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
        </measurements>
      </element>
    </elements>
  </content>
  <sensor-info>
    <serial-number>D5:88:63:98:AA:E2</serial-number>
    <ip-address>192.168.1.99</ip-address>
    <name>somename</name>
    <group></group>
    <device-type>XYZ</device-type>
  </sensor-info>
</response>
```

The issue I'm facing now is that I have no working idea on how to dig deeper than  in the levels to retrieve the values 145 and 1. I think I have to make use of the attribute fw / bw.

```
          <value label="fw">145</value>
          <value label="bw">1</value>
```

My code so far, which returns an error:

> Cannot find method getChild(). (line 53, file "Code")

```
function xmlRead(){
  
  var url = 'SOMEURL';
  var responseXML = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  var outputDocument = XmlService.parse(responseXML);
  var ns = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.xovis.com/sensor-api/v2");  
  
  var out = outputDocument.getRootElement().getChildren()[2].getChildren();

  var fw = out.getChild();
  
  Logger.log(out);
 
   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drill down in the XML by selecting specific childs.
In the example below I made it dynamic, assuming there may be multiple `element` and `measurement` nodes.

Made this quickly and is not tested. There may be some typos but the mechanism should be clear I think. Make sure to check the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#).

```
var xml = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><response xmlns="http://www.xovis.com/sensor-api/v2"><sensor-time timezone="Europe/Berlin">2017-12-18T17:00:02+01:00</sensor-time><status><code>OK</code></status><content><elements><element><element-id>0</element-id><element-name>count</element-name><sensor-type>somesensor</sensor-type><data-type>LINE</data-type><from>2017-10-29T16:00:00+01:00</from><to>2017-10-29T17:00:00+01:00</to><resolution>ONE_HOUR</resolution><measurements><measurement><from>2017-10-29T16:00:00+01:00</from><to>2017-10-29T17:00:00+01:00</to><values><value label="fw">145</value><value label="bw">1</value></values></measurement></measurements></element></elements></content><sensor-info><serial-number>D5:88:63:98:AA:E2</serial-number><ip-address>192.168.1.99</ip-address><name>somename</name><group></group><device-type>XYZ</device-type></sensor-info></response>';

function myFunction() {
  var outputDocument = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var ns = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.xovis.com/sensor-api/v2");
  var content = outputDocument.getRootElement().getChild('content', ns);
  var elements = content.getChild('elements', ns).getChildren('element', ns);

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { // Loop over each element
        Logger.log('Element ID: '+elements[i].getChild('element-id', ns).getText());
        var measurements = elements[i].getChild('measurements', ns).getChildren('measurement', ns);
        for (var j = 0; j < measurements.length; j++) { // Loop over each measurement
            Logger.log('Measurement from: '+measurements[j].getChild('from', ns).getText())
            var values = measurements[j].getChild('values', ns).getChildren('value', ns);
            for (var k = 0; k < values.length; k++) { // loop over each value
                Logger.log('Value: '+values[k].getText())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is returning the same error as before when using your code:
TypeError: Cannot call method "getChild" of null. (line 68, file "Code")

var content is also null when running debug mode

Comment: What happens when you debug `outputDocument.getRootElement()`?

Comment: [17-12-19 14:26:13:171 CET] null

Comment: but it returns [17-12-19 14:28:31:860 CET] [Element: <content [Namespace: http://www.xovis.com/sensor-api/v2]/>] when I replace the getRootElement with: 
var content = outputDocument.getRootElement().getChildren()[2];

Comment: @dan_ke I've updated my answer with a tested version. In my previous code I failed to select the content node due to not providing the namespace.